# wix MaskedEdit w/paste?

Tags: wix

I'm trying to add a MaskedEdit (for a serial) control to a Wix project I have. I have the following added:

```
<Property Id="PIDTemplate">
  <![CDATA[?????-?????-?????-?????-?????-?????]]>
</Property>
<Control Id="Edit" Type="MaskedEdit" X="97" Y="141" Width="191" Height="17" Property="SERIALNUMBER" Text="[PIDTemplate]" TabSkip="no" />
```

Which allows me to have a Alphabetical/Numerial key. The only problem is, when I paste a key into the first field (either the fill key, or hyphen seperated), it only pastes the first field and not the rest. Do I need to do my own handling for this to work?

Also the control is not opaque. Any ideas how to fix this? (Transparent is only available on Text controls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are constraints of the underlying MSI internal UI controls.  There isn't anything you can do about it without writing your own external UI handler ( level of effort = massive )

Comment: Thanks Chris! You seem to be a champ on Wix questions. I only wish their documentation was as up to par as you!

Comment: It just comes from years of Windows Installer work.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368039(v=VS.85).aspx   Notice the Text control type has a transparent attribute and MaskedEdit doesn't.

Comment: The level of effort to create external UI doesn't have to be massive if you use an existing product that simplifies this task. One such product is SharpSetup.

Comment: You should disclose that you make SharpSetup to avoid the impression of comment spam. Yes, I could use an InstallShield InstallScript MSI project type or SharpSetup (requires .net 2.0 right?) but it's still true that it's a massive operation to write your own external UI handler.

Comment: Yes, it requires .NET 2.0 at runtime. The question is whether your objective is to write external UI handler (unlikely, but the effort is indeed massive) or just create an installer that doesn't have dependency on crappy MSI UI (in which case you might want to look for tools that will simplify your job; the tools might introduce other dependencies though). BTW, the information that I'm the author of SharpSetup is pretty clearly visible both on my SO user page (website field) and SharpSetup website.